# Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element' in ExtJS 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, extjs4, extjs5

I am trying for using `Ext.dom.Query.Select` method to find all divs which having class name square and highlightedReactangle.Same method was working with `extjs 4` , but after up grading to `extjs 5` it start throwing error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on
>   'Element':
>   'div:any(div.square|div.highlightedReactangle|div.highlightedReactangleIE|div.pin|div.redCircleCount|div.stampPreviewCls)'
>   is not a valid selector.

The statement I'm using to find related div is,

```
this.el.select("div:any(div.square|div.highlightedReactangle|div.highlightedReactangleIE|div.pin|div.redCircleCount|div.stampPreviewCls)", true);
```

what exactely I'm missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what exactely I'm missing ?

From version 5, when `select` is called on [`Element`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-select) (versus explicitly using [`Ext.dom.Query.select`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.dom.Query-method-select)), Ext JS uses the native [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method which requires valid CSS selectors. As the error message suggests, your selector is not a [valid one](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/).

In version 4, Ext JS used `Ext.dom.Query.select` for processing `select` calls on `Element`s. That method is more "liberal" than `querySelectorAll`. It will work in version 5 as well, so you can just use:

```
Ext.dom.Query.select(your_selector, this.el.dom)
```

Comment: @Dark, I'm able to select element using selector..Don't have have problem with `this.el.select()` method...I have problem with using syntax...`this.el.select("div.redCircleCount")` return four element but how should I collect all element with this pattern `this.el.select("div.redCircleCount | div.square")`  ?

Comment: I also tried your way...`this.el.select("div.redCircleCount")` returns 4 element exactly whereas `Ext.dom.Query.select("div.redCircleCount",this.el);` returns empty array

Comment: The pattern I'm trying for `E:any(S1|S2|S2) an E element which matches any of the simple selectors S1, S2 or S3`

Comment: @AbhijitMuke the second argument to `Ext.dom.Query.select` must be `this.el.dom` not `this.el`. Big difference!