# Update data function is not updating value in database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, web

I have created  `get_data(id)` and `update_data()` function in `item.js` file and corresponding `get_data.php` and `update_data.php` files. In my code `get_data(id)` function is working perfectly but `update_data()`is not updating the value in database. It seems like function is not calling `update_data.php`. I've tried implementing ajax and php for the first time, Please help me to figure out the exact problem in my code. Here is my code

```
        function loadItem(id) {
            console.log(id);
            $.ajax({
                url: "get_data.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {'id': id},
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    var d = JSON.parse(result);
                    
                    document.getElementById("ib_id").value = d.category[0].ic_id;
    document.getElementById("ib_name").value = d.category[0].ic_name;
    
                }
            });
        }
    
        function updateItem() {
    
            var id = document.getElementById("ib_id").value;
            var name = document.getElementById("ib_name").value;
            $.ajax({
                url: "update_data.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {'id': id, 'name': name},
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
        }
```

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Test Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1>Test Page</h1>
    
        <button onclick="loadItem(2);">Load Data</button>
    
    
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    
        <form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="ib_id" id="ib_id" class="form-control" 
                                                        placeholder="id etc."  required/>
        <input type="text" name="ib_name" id="ib_name" value="" class="form-control" 
                                                            placeholder="i.e HP, Dell, Sony etc."  required/>
    
    
    
                                                      
        <br/>      <button onclick="updateItem();">Update Data </button>
                                                        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"> 
         </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/item.js"></script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

get_data.php

```
        <?php
        include 'connection.php';
        $id=$_POST["id"];
        
        $category = array();
        $temp = array();
        $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM item_category WHERE ic_id = ".$id);
        //$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM item_category");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $temp['ic_id'] = $row['ic_id'];
            $temp['ic_name'] = $row['ic_name'];
            array_push($category, $temp);
        }
        
        $response['category'] = $category;
        echo json_encode($response);
        
        ?>
```

update_data.php

```
            <?php
        include 'connection.php';
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        echo "id is".$id;
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        
        $query = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE item_category SET ic_name = '$name' WHERE ic_id = ".$id);
    
        echo "updated";
        ?>
```

Comment: The line that executes `mysqli_query()` in `update_data.php` appears to be commented out...

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: I have updated the code but still update button is not calling php

Comment: @AyeshaYaseen: What specific debugging have you done to confirm this conclusion?  When you use your browser's debugging tools, are there any errors at all on the browser's development console?  In the script debugger, is the `updateItem` function invoked at all?  In the network tab, is the AJAX request made?  Does it contain the data you expect?  What is the server's response?

Comment: There is no input with the id `ib_id` so `document.getElementById("ib_id").value` won't return any id at all.

Comment: @David Debugger displays exception on `var id = document.getElementById("ib_id").value;` --- TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading

Comment: @Ayes: The error is telling you that you can't read the value of an element which doesn't exist.  There is no `id="ib_id"` element in your HTML.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson yes I forgot to make another field for id. I have now updated my code but debugger displays another exception "DOM EXCEPTION" -failed to execute

Comment: If you get an error, please post the complete error message so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Error Solved. I added the input field and it worked .Thank you @David

Comment: I've found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50519829/domexception-failed-to-execute-queryselectorall-on-element-when-using-an) regarding "DOM EXCEPTION". Thank you @Magnus